# Json object in jade file .and that Json object contains Array also

Tags: node.js, pug

I am new jade,can u explain how to display the `Json` object in `Jade` file, and that `Json` object contains *Array* also  please refer below `Json` Object

how to read this Json Object in jade file

```
{
    "output": {
        "ftp-job": [
            {
                "destination-cape": [
                    {
                        "action Code": 45,
                        "action Needed": "FILE_NO_ACCESS",
                        "byte Transferred": 10000,
                        "codename": "Chongqing",
                        "expectational": "3/4/2015",
                        "file Name": "Spiderman3",
                        "percent Completed": 34,
                        "total Bytes": 100008
                    }
                ],
                "job Status": "IN_PROGRESS",
                "source": {
                    "cpeName": "LA",
                    "file Name": "steadfast"
                },
                "start Date": "03/04/2014",
                "tenant-id": "Oxide",
                "user-id": "admin Joe"
            }
        ],
        "result": "OK"
    }
  }
```

This is the error i can read:

> C:\node\nodetest2\views\userlist.jade:9 7| each user1, i in
>   userlist 8| li > 9| a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")=
>   (user1.ftp-job.destination-cpe.actionCode) 10| Cannot read property
>   'destination' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

From what i can understant from the error message, seems only a typo:

```
a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")= (user1.ftp-job.destination-cpe.actionCode)
```

should be as already mentioned by @Scimonster

```
a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")= (user1["ftp-job"]["destination-cape"]["action Code"])
```

How you can read from that [page](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#variables), you can read from `JSON` object simply in this manner:

from this `JSON`:

```
{"book": {"name": "pippo"}}
```

you will read the *book.name* with regular `JavaScript` `.` notation

```
foo = book.name + " world"
h1= foo
```

result

```
<h1>pippo world</h1>
```

Comment: h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user1, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")= (user1.ftp-job.destination-cpe.actionCode)

Comment: it showing C:\node\nodetest2\views\userlist.jade:9 7| each user1, i in userlist 8| li > 9| a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")= (user1.ftp-job.destination-cpe.actionCode) 10| Cannot read property 'destination' of undefined

Comment: i am sending Json Obj like data = JSON.parse(data);  res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" :JSON.stringify(data),
        });    and in jade file i am reading like this     h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user1, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")= (user1.ftp-job.destination-cape.actionCode)    it showing error msg like   C:\node\nodetest2\views\userlist.jade:9 7| each user1, i in userlist 8| li > 9| a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")= (user1.ftp-job.destination-cpe.actionCode) 10| Cannot read property 'destination' of undefined

Comment: i am Sending J son Object to jade file like                         data = JSON.parse(data);                       res.render('userlist', {"userlist" :JSON.stringify(data), });                  And I am Reading That Json Object like                                                                
     User List
    ul
        each user1, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")= (user1.ftp-job.destination-cpe.actionCode)                                  And It showing Error like (Cannot read property 'destination' of undefined)

Comment: @user3475175 please read your edited question and my edited answer

Comment: it Showing Same results

Comment: It is not Working can u check it once please

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (so Jade, by extension) cannot access properties containing "special characters" via dot notation.

```
a(href="mailto:#{user1.result}")= (user1['ftp-job']['destination-cape']['action Code'])
```

It was interpreting it as a few expressions. `user1.ftp - job.destination - cpe.actionCode`. Needless to say, those last two variables don't exist.

Comment: there is also a typo destination-cpe doesn't exist

Comment: can u tell which way we have to send json object to jade file

Comment: @user3475175 In Express, pass `user1` in the locals object. See the [Express docs on `res.locals` and `res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals)